# Theorems related to decomposition of a matrix into square of stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, optimization, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am looking for theorems that say when a stochastic matrix can be written as a square of some stochastic matrix.

If anyone could point out any links or papers, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such theorem because the statement isn't true. Consider $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ for instance. It has a negative determinant and hence it cannot possibly be the square of a stochastic matrix. For some conditions concerning the existence of $p$-th roots of stochastic matrices, see Higham and Lin, [*On $p$th roots of stochastic matrices*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2010.04.007), LAA 435(2001): 448-463.

Comment: It feels to me that it would work if and only if the eigen values of the matrix are in $\{ 0, 1 \}$, however I cannot prove it. I was going to try with take the square root of the Jordan normal form to show that it cannot be stochastic in general but, I'm guessing there could be other decomposition.

Comment: @P.Quinton Sorry, I have misread your comment multiple times. A $2\times2$ stochastic matrix $A$ has a stochastic matrix square root if and only if its eigenvalues are nonnegative (or equivalently, iff $\det(A)\ge0$). In fact, if $A=B^2$ for some real matrix $B$ (be it stochastic or not), then $\det(A)=\det(B)^2\ge0$. Since one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $1$, the other eigenvalue must be nonnegative. Conversely, if the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $a\ge0$, then $A=B^2$ where $B=(A+\sqrt{a}I)/(1+\sqrt{a})$ is a stochastic matrix.